# Excel Services In External Website

Tags: 2013, excel-services, excel-web-access-webpart

I'd like to render an excel workbook (specifically a pivot table) using Excel Services on our department's internal website and I am not sure how to do it (and I guess I am not searching correctly on Google, because I am not seeing what I want there either).  We are using SharePoint 2013 and I have a page on a subsite that uses Excel Services to render a pivot table that connects to an external database.

A little more than a decade ago I made a web page that used Office Web Components to include a pivot table in web page I made and that is what I want (but I cannot use OWC because that was discontinued by Microsoft and I read that Excel Services is Microsoft's designated replacement for Office Web Components).

Right now I can create an iframe on our internal website that points at the page on our sharepoint server but I get all the sharepoint menus and headers in the iframe which is not what I want.    Maybe the solution is to just to hide all the sharepoint stuff outside of the Excel Services rendering (but I do not know how to do that) or maybe there is a way to include that Excel Web Access web part in external web pages (also do not know how to do this).  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a SharePoint page you could use the query parameter IsDlg=1 to strip out most of the stuff. You could also use the Excel Services REST api to just retrieve the html directly.

Comment: Is it opening with Excel Services or with standard in browser support?

Comment: @theChrisKent, thanks!  Next week I will look into the REST api and how to retrieve the html directly as well as IsDlg (which sounds like it might be the easiest path to what I am trying to do)

Comment: @Graham, do you mean Excel Services vs. Excel Web App?  It is opening with Excel Services.  I am not sure of what you meant by "standard in-browser support".